# How do I configure Webstorm to work with servers using XAMPP?

Tags: angularjs, xampp, webstorm

I'm trying to use web servers that I wrote in my project, and I'm using XAMPPP.
Is there any configuration that I need to change in webstorm so my project files would be automatically saved in the xampp directory?

Comment: If project is located elsewhere -- just setup Deployment to copy your project files to desired location at `Settings | Deployment`. Or just create your project in desired location in first place.

Comment: see http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Sync+changes+and+automatic+upload+to+a+deployment+server+in+PhpStorm